# How do I install multiple old package versions in conda venv?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Attempting to set up virtual environment based on Python 3.5 and Windows 10. Instructions: https://github.com/jakevdp/PythonDataScienceHandbook/blob/master/README.md#software

When running command `conda create -n PDSH python=3.5 --file requirements.txt`

Error:

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - pillow==3.4.2
  - scikit-learn==0.17.1
  - seaborn==0.7.0
  - numpy==1.11.1
  - pandas==0.18.1
  - matplotlib==1.5.1
  - scipy==0.17.1
  - scikit-image==0.12.3
```

When attempting to change seaborn to different versions(found at https://seaborn.pydata.org/whatsnew.html) I get the same error.

How do I find the correct versions to download? Are there resources online that address this? Are there complications with installing multiple packages?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the installation instructions:

> Note that some of these exact version numbers may not be available on your platform: you may have to tweak them for your own use

On macOS, using the conda-forge channel, the following works just fine:

`conda create -n test-env python=3.5 pillow scikit-learn seaborn numpy pandas matplotlib scipy scikit-image numexpr pandas-datareader netcdf4`

As the repo mentions, I would not be surprised if everything worked on the most recent versions with only a few tweaks.